# How can I easily test & visualize different math things?

Tags: physics, simulations

For example, I've asked about the breakout formula to calculate the ball bounce. Inside of XNA, I don't know where I would code this and to even display something I would need a lot of code.

Is there something simple way visualize math formulas such as the one above?

Comment: If you're up for learning a new language, the [R language](http://www.r-project.org/) is designed specifically for visualizing pure math. [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) is another language geared toward visualization.

Comment: You can use [MatLab](http://www.mathworks.com/), but I personally dont. Whenever I want to type out a bunch of quick code to test a formula, I actually use the python interpreter. Python is great for something like this, and running something in the interpreter is really quick and easy.

Comment: I asked something like this some time ago in Stackoverflow.com and the [answers are pretty good.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488502/best-language-to-program-some-math-free-fast-easy-cool-etc) I ended up using [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) and it was awesome.

Comment: For graphing formulas I usually use https://www.desmos.com/calculator which is straightforward to use, and free.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to reason through problems on plain old **pencil and paper**. There's just nothing quite like it; it's completely unstructured.

Otherwise, I mean, there are math problems like Maple, Matlab or Mathematica (those are the popular three) but they of course have a learning curve.

Figuring out that particular problem was mostly just a matter of reasoning; define exactly what you want to accomplish, what variables you need (intersection point, velocity of ball, distance of intersection from center of paddle, minimum and maximum speeds), and then determine **how to go from what you have to what you want**.

Sometimes maybe it just takes being familiar with the math too, or having solved similar problems or understanding different angles of the problem. For example, I had already seen similar problems like this one in my Calculus classes, so it was pretty easy for me to tackle. Math is important in game development.